# in R, why does the column name change when creating a new row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a loop below to create new variables and making it a new column. But created column names are..something wrong. I want it to be "cat1", "cat2",...  "cat9". However, the name of the new columns is "cat1....a..1..", "cat2....a..2.." "cat3....a..3.."

Is it the wrong way to define a column name like this? cat1 <- a[[1]].
From "id" to "head" column names are okay whit this way.

```
summary_cat_df <- data.frame()
id=1
idx=4
for (j in 1:length(cat_id_files)){ #44
  for (i in 1:length(cat_id_files[[j]])){ #10
    a <- summary_cat(cat_id_files[[j]][i], j, i)
    if(j %% 4 ==1){
      new_row <- data.frame(id=idx_list[[j]][i], type=name_list[[j]][i], iter=i, eye = "c", head="f", cat1 <- a[[1]], cat2 <- a[[2]], cat3 <- a[[3]], cat4 <- a[[4]], cat5 <- a[[5]], cat6 <- a[[6]], cat7 <- a[[7]], cat8 <- a[[8]], cat9 <- a[[9]])
     # column names are cat1....a..1..", "cat2....a..2.." not "cat1", "cat2",... "cat9".
    }
    summary_cat_df<- rbind(summary_cat_df, new_row)
  }
}
```

```
# the return value of summary_cat() is a dataframe
summary_cat <- function(df, j, i){
  cat_1 =0 
  cat_2 =0 
  cat_3 =0 
  cat_4 =0 
  cat_5 =0 
  cat_6 =0 
  cat_7 =0 
  cat_8 =0 
  cat_9 =0 
  cat_10 =0 
  cat_11 =0

  row_num <- nrow(get(cat_id_files[[j]][i]))
  row_num2 <- row_num -1
  for (k in 1: row_num2){
  
    temp_value <- get(cat_id_files[[j]][i])$slope_deviations_cat[[k]]
    #print(temp_value)
    
    if(temp_value == 1 ){
      cat_1 <- cat_1 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 2 ){
      cat_2 <- cat_2 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 3 ){
      cat_3 <- cat_3 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 4 ){
      cat_4 <- cat_4 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 5 ){
      cat_5 <- cat_5 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 6 ){
      cat_6 <- cat_6 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 7 ){
      cat_7 <- cat_7 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 8 ){
      cat_8 <- cat_8 + 1
    }else if(temp_value == 9 ){
      cat_9 <- cat_9 + 1
    }else if(is.na(temp_value)){
      print("NA")
    }
  }
  result<-data.frame(cat_1 = cat_1,
                     cat_2 = cat_2,
                     cat_3 = cat_3,
                     cat_4 = cat_4,
                     cat_5 = cat_5,
                     cat_6 = cat_6,
                     cat_7 = cat_7,
                     cat_8 = cat_8,
                     cat_9 = cat_9)
  return(result)
}


> a <- summary_cat(cat_id_files[[1]][1], 1, 1)

> a
  cat_1 cat_2 cat_3 cat_4 cat_5 cat_6 cat_7 cat_8 cat_9

1    80     0    87     0     0     0    68     0   246

> a[1]
  cat_1
1    80
```

Simply, to solve this problem I can use

```
colnames(summary_cat_df)[6] <- "cat1"
```

Still, I wonder why the column names defined like this, 'cat1....a..1 '?

Any comments to improve the code would be great. I'm still learning!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks overly complicated but to solve the name issue you could do smthg like:

```
new_row <- data.frame(id=idx_list[[j]][i], type=name_list[[j]][i], iter=i, eye = "c", head="f")
new_row <- cbind(new_row, a)
```

I suspect the issue coming from your use of `<-` instead of `=` to define the `cat` columns in `new_row`

Comment: I think my code is messy, too. why didn't I think of the cbind()!!!.  This is a much simpler way to write the code and it works. Thanks a lot!  Also, it seems like your inspection is right. Using `=` instead of `<-`, defined the name what I wanted. I didn't notice that I used `<- `...

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers